# Sample code linking visibility of Google Maps markers to the visibility of rows of jqGrid table?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jqgrid, dom-events

After I filter the rows in a jqGrid table, based on [jqGrud](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)'s column searches, I would the visibility of a set of Google Map markers associated with the table rows to automatically reflect the filtered results.

As a model/template for me, I am looking for javascript sample code 'out there' which  interactively links a set of Google Map markers to the rows of a jqGrid table?

Or advise on how to proceed coding this interactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too specific, the chance of finding a canned example of such detail is unlikely.

A good place to start for you would be Mike's tutorial on marker categories that gives you a basic technique for showing/hiding groups of Markers.

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/categories.htm

Once you've understood that, and you've got your head fully around jqGrid you should be on your way.

Duncan.